# jQuery: Remover linha de tabela

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou tentando remover as linhas da tabela onde, na coluna Funcionário, o nome não contém a sequência "oã", como fiz no código abaixo. O problema é que mesmo retornando falso para a comparação se "oã" está contido em "José", a linha não é excluída.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Código</th>
        <th>Funcionário</th>
        <th>Cargo</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>João</td>
        <td>Analista de Sistemas</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Maria</td>
        <td>Advogada</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>José</td>
        <td>Engenheiro Civil</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Joãozinho</td>
        <td>Desenvolvedor</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('table td:nth-child(2)').each(function(indice){
            var txtDigitado = "Oã";
            var pattern = new RegExp(txtDigitado, 'i');

            var item_celula = $(this).text();

            if(pattern.test(item_celula)) {
              $('table tbody tr').eq(indice+1).remove();
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

Comment: Você tem algum botão na linha? Ou essa remoção é estatica?

Comment: Olá Marconi. É estática. Na verdade a variável "txtDigitado" vai pegar o valor digitado no campo, mas fiz dessa forma ai para resumir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amigo, tive que modificar uma pouco sua função, mas acho que deu certo. Peguei primeiro a linha da tabela que queremos excluir, fiz um loop e nele apliquei o seu teste. Quando ele retorna 'falso' a linha é excluída:

```
(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //pega a 'tr' no corpo da tabela
        $('table tbody tr').each(function(indice){
            var txtDigitado = "Oã";
            var pattern = new RegExp(txtDigitado, 'i');

            //pega o texto na 2a. 'td'
            var item_celula = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text();

            if(pattern.test(item_celula) == false) {
                //caso passe no teste, remove a linha atual
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Valeu Hugo! me ajudou muito.